# Массив из 4-х байт

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть число `int(32)`. Как его конвертировать в массив байтов с MSB first? 
Перечитал все что нашел о "GetByte", но у меня с этим методом почему-то число просто переносится в конец масива из четырех байт.
То есть, введя число, скажем 10, я получаю `0, 0, 0, 10`...
Как сделать, чтобы число именно разбивалось на 4 байта.

Comment: `var array = BitConverter.GetBytes(10);`?

Comment: Для массива байтов нет понятия "MSB first". `[0,0,0,10]` - представление 32-х разрядного числа 10 в виде отдельных байтов. А что не так?

Comment: в один байт влезает числа 0-255, так что сложно будет разбить число 10 на целых 4 байта, если первые будут отличные от нуля.

Comment: @MBo предположу, что ТС хочет `[10, 0, 0, 0]` вместо `[0, 0, 0, 10]` - что, собственно, `BitConverter.GetBytes(10)` и возвращает

Comment: так вы и получили 4 байта, как и хотели. Просто число `10` помещается в 1 байт, поэтому остальные байты - нули

Comment: @tym32167 Не исключено, но пока желания его неясны, тем более с учетом фразы об MSB.

Comment: @MBo запасаемся попкорном, ждем ТСа :)

Comment: Почитайте про `BigEndian`/`LittleEndian`

Comment: да, на счет того что я получал 10 в конце это верно. Я забыл что в каждом байте помещаеться значение 0-255... Мой косяк

Comment: Порядок байтов можно поменять методом `System.Net.IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder`. И обратный ему метод `HostToNetworkOrder`.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо за советы. Про BigEndian/LittleEndian я прочел.
Решение нашел:)
Дело в том что, апликация для управления мотором посылает на драйвер мотора команду в виде 9 байт. где байты с 4 по 7 это значене на которое нужно двигаться.
И он может пулучать их только так...
Решение что я сделал, конвертировал

> int в .String("X8")

затем получил хекс строку, 
разбил и конвертировал ее на 4 байта. и после подставил 4 байта в массив(команды) из 9 байт. 
П.С если интересно вот кусок кода что я в итоге использую:

> ```
> private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//HOME button
>         {
>             port.Write(M_home, 0, M_home.Length); (9 байт команды)
>             port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);(9 байт ответа)
>             arr1[0] = buffer[4];(1 байт значения)
>             arr1[1] = buffer[5];(2 байт значения)
>             arr1[2] = buffer[6];(3 байт значения)
>             arr1[3] = buffer[7];(4 байт значения)
>             string var = ByteArrayToString(arr1);
>             int r = int.Parse(var, 
>                                System.Globalization.
>                                NumberStyles.HexNumber);
>             textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(r);
>         }
> ```

Comment: Что-то вы перемудрили. Использование `BitConverter.GetBytes`, как вам предложили первым же комментом, явно проще.

Comment: Да все было бы просто если бы драйвер просто брал число и разбивал его на 4 байта... Но это походу для слабаков, поскольку он делит число на 4 части от младшего к старшему и переводит все это дело в хекс значение. И ответ на операцию приходит в виде хекс значений. По этому приходиться все это дело конвертировать из массива байтов в хекс строку, а после хекс стороку обратно в инт.. Легкий гемор 

Comment: Ещё раз: у вас есть массив байтов (длиной 4), вам нужно получить из него int. Зачем вы используете промежуточную строку? Переводите байты сразу в число.

Comment: так как значение приходит не просто как разбитое число на 4 байта. а как число разбитое на 4 байт где знаечение каждого из байт как хекс число. И если просто сложить все хекс значения и конвертировать в инт, получаеться хрень. По этому и такой вариат только прокатил, перевести хекс в значения в байтовые и после уже конвертировать все это в инт.

Comment: Число - это число. Hex - это визуальное представление числа. Римские цифры - это тоже вариант визуального представления числа. Выкиньте работу со строками, она не нужна.